# Is it normal for a Google Sheets Add-On module to be reloaded on every google.script.run call?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am developing a Google Sheets Add-On and as part of it on the client side I am periodically (every 100 ms) calling an exposed function that returns currently selected cell. Its code looks like this:

```js
function getCurrSelectedCell()  {
    let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    return {current: `${sheet.getName()}!${sheet.getActiveCell().getA1Notation()}`};
}
```

I call this function via `google.script.run`, and while it works just fine it is is slow and execution time has high variance. The call can complete within a second or within 5 or even 10 seconds.

I added the following trace at module level:

```js
console.log("module reloaded ");
```

So what I can see is that the module is loaded on every remote function call ! My gas module is compiled with tsc and webpack which bundles all the dependencies I need. It is then pushed as a single server.gs file via clasp. Module size is around 1 MB. If this module gets loaded on every call then it makes sense that it may contribute to the slowness.

Does anybody know if this behavior of reloading module is a normal behavior after add-on has been deployed to production (i.e. to market place), or just something that happens only when add-on is being deployed in development test mode (Deploy-> Test deployments) ?

What I am expecting is that module gets loaded once, at the time add-on is loaded into the sheet.